# Loop through a container and remove divs without a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this has a simple solution. Maybe because it is late but I have hit a wall. I have a container `div #jewelsContainer` with a list of child divs inside. I am grabbing it in an object like this:

```
var existingBoardItems = $('#jewelsContainer').html();
```

this object produces a list of all the divs inside the `#jewelsContainer` container div

i.e. BEFORE

```
<div class="jewel jewel_5" data-row="1" data-col="0" data-jewel="5" style="left: 0px; top: 40px;"></div>
<div class="jewel jewel_3" data-row="0" data-col="3" data-jewel="3" style="top: 0px; left: 120px;"></div>
<div class="jewel jewel_5" data-row="0" data-col="4" data-jewel="5" style="top: 0px; left: 160px;"></div>
<div class="jewel jewel_4" data-row="0" data-col="5" data-jewel="4" style="top: 0px; left: 200px;"></div>
<div class="aff_score" style="left:0px; top:0px;">+10</div>
...
```

AFTER

```
<div class="jewel jewel_5" data-row="1" data-col="0" data-jewel="5" style="left: 0px; top: 40px;"></div>
<div class="jewel jewel_3" data-row="0" data-col="3" data-jewel="3" style="top: 0px; left: 120px;"></div>
<div class="jewel jewel_5" data-row="0" data-col="4" data-jewel="5" style="top: 0px; left: 160px;"></div>
<div class="jewel jewel_4" data-row="0" data-col="5" data-jewel="4" style="top: 0px; left: 200px;"></div>
...
```

I need to loop through all the divs in this object and remove any div that does NOT have a class .jewel then set a localStorage for the newly created object

```
localStorage.setItem('existingBoardItems',NEWELY CREATED OBJECT);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector at this context, and there is no need to iterate all the divs.

```
$('#jewelsContainer div:not(.jewel)').remove();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/S3uh2/)

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was an easy fix. I must get some sleep.

Answer (score 3):

Although an answer has been accepted, I feel the non-jQuery solution should be present as well. `:not` is not a jQuery selector, it's a CSS selector that is supported in both jQuery and in the native `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`.

Removing said elements could be something like this:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('#container :not(.a)'), function(e,i){
    e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
})
```

or this:

```
var elms = document.querySelectorAll('#container :not(.a)');
for (var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
    elms[i].parentNode.removeChild(elms[i]);
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8HPLM/1/)

And here is a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/anotherjqvsvanilla) that shows that vanilla is more than twice as fast in this case. Edit: seems it's only faster on chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
$('#jewelsContainer').find('div').each(function () {
   if (!$(this).hasClass('jewel')) {
        $(this).remove()
    }
});
localStorage.setItem('existingBoardItems',$('#jewelsContainer').html());
console.log(localStorage.getItem('existingBoardItems'));
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7M8xL/2/)

Comment: This would not remove this element.. `<div class="jewel_4"   ..."></div>`.. Use `.hasClass(jewel)` instead..

Comment: why can you explain what wrong with sridhar code. I think it works

Comment: @SridharR Now see.. http://jsfiddle.net/7M8xL/1/ . OP wants to remove elements which don't have the class `jewel`.. But this code would consider `jewel_4` is as same as `jewel`